# Need help understanding logistic regression output with seemingly contradictory results after swapping reference group

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, odds-ratio, categorical-encoding

Some background, each of these predictors are 0, 1 one-hot-encoded categories that represent items in a basket (think e-commerce). Each observation can have multiple 1s. For instance, a single observation can have both x1 and x2 and x3, and not purchase x4, or any other items, resulting in a vector such as (1,1,1,0,0,0,0). The aim is to find the odds of Y occurring when purchasing X1,X2,X3 etc.

I have the following logistic regression odds, where X1 is the reference group:

```
| -         | pvalue  | odds    |
|-----------|---------|---------|
| X2        | 0       | 1.58781 |
| X3        | 0       | 1.37795 |
| X4        | 0       | 1.31701 |
| X5        | 0.00038 | 1.05357 |
| X6        | 0.00583 | 0.95571 |
| X7        | 0       | 0.5504  |
| INTERCEPT | 0       | 0.45808 |
```

Based on this, my interpretation could include something such as "Compared to X1, X2 has 1.58 times the odds of the outcome"

However, if I switch the reference group to X2 I get the following:

```
| -         | pvalue  | odds    |
|-----------|---------|---------|
| X3        | 0       | 1.46834 |
| X4        | 0       | 1.34498 |
| X1        | 0       | 1.2982  |
| X5        | 0       | 1.12634 |
| X6        | 0       | 0.57685 |
| X7        | 0.47621 | 1.01191 |
| INTERCEPT | 0       | 0.43695 |
```

Now I can say something such as, "Compared to X2, X1 has 1.29 times the odds of the outcome". However, I feel like this contradicts the results, because when X1 is the reference group I also get an increased odds...I would expect by swapping the reference groups, I would get odds that are less than 1 for X1.

Why would something like this occur?

Comment: The outcome does not make sense to me (coefficients $x_7>x_6$ or $x_6>x_7$ depending on the case). How do you perform the regression? Why do you have a regression with leaving one of the regressors ($x_1$ or $x_2$) out of the regression? To get these extreme changes in coefficients you must be having strong correlations between the regresssors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results differ because you are actually fitting two different models, one where you adjust for all predictors except for $x_1$, and another where you adjust for all predictors except $x_2$. What's happening is that you are trying to treat the vector of predictors $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$ as dummy variables by assuming that one needs to be omitted from the model. If they *were* dummy variables, then that would be the right thing to do, because any one $x_i$ is a deterministic function of the remaining $x$'s and your model would not be identified if you adjusted for all variables. However, you indicated in your background that the predictors are indicator variables having no deterministic relationship.

**Upshot**: you need to adjust for all of the predictors in your model, as in $\mathrm{logit}\Pr(Y=1|x_1, \ldots, x_7) = \beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^7 x_j \beta_j$. There is an intercept plus a coefficient for each of your predictors. My presumption here is that no predictor can be written as a linear combination of the other predictors.

Also, the way you worded your model interpretation is not quite right. The interpretation of the coefficient estimate corresponding to $x_2$ in your first model would be the following: "For fixed values of $x_3$, $x_4$, ..., $x_7$, the odds of the outcome occurring multiplicatively increase by 1.58 when $x_2$ is in the basket versus when it is not"

Comment: Thank you for your help! This makes much more sense to me now

Comment: Hey, I was reading your comment again this morning, and was hoping you can give me a bit more clarity. How would I adjust the predictors in the model given that their indicator variables? One thing I did was create actual dummy variables by recategorizing certain combinations of indicator variables such as "purchased x2 and something else, purchased only things that are not x2, purchased only x2". Is this what you mean by adjusting?

Comment: What I mean when I say 'adjusting' is the following model: $\mathrm{logit} \Pr(Y = 1|x_1, \ldots, x_7) = \beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^7 x_j\beta_j$, which assumes that each item in your basket will multiplicatively change the odds of the outcome occurring. If you suspect that when certain combinations of items in a basket would change the odds in a non-multiplicative fashion, then you might also include all pairwise, or even higher order, interactions in your model (assuming you have enough observations to fit such a model). I've clarified my original response based on your comment.